# Como diminuir números decimais

Tags: javascript, sintaxe, divisão

Como diminuir os números decimais dessa tabuada de divisão ? tava pensando em colocar um `tofixed()`, mas estou com dificuldade de achar uma sintaxe correta pra encaixar nesse código. como posso resolver isso, alguém pode ajudar?

```js
function tabuada() {
    let num = document.getElementById('txtn')
    let tab4 = document.getElementById('seltab4')
    if (num.value.length == 0) {
        window.alert('digite um numero!')
    } else {
        let n = Number(num.value) 
        let c = 1 
        tab4.innerHTML = ''
        while (c <= 10) { 
            let item4 = document.createElement('option') 
            item4.text = `${n} / ${c} = ${n/c}` 
            item4.value = `tab4${c}` 
            tab4.appendChild(item4) 
            c++ 
        }
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="estilo.css">
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <h1>Tabuada</h1>
</header>
<section>
    <div>
        <p>Numero: <input type="number" name="num" id="txtn">
        <input type="button" value="Gerar tabuada" onclick="tabuada()"></p>
    </div>
    
    <div>
        <select name="Tabuada4" id="seltab4" size="10" ></select>
    </div>

</section> 

<script src="aula06.js"></script>  
</body>
</html>
```

[image: Tabuada]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dentro última da expressão(resultado) embutida na string:

`item4.text = ${n} / ${c} = ${n/c}`

Coloque um parênteses `()` em torno de `n/c` e nesse valor evoque o método `toFixed()`:

`item4.text = ${n} / ${c} = ${(n/c).toFixed(2)}`

No seu código:

```js
function tabuada() {
    let num = document.getElementById('txtn')
    let tab4 = document.getElementById('seltab4')
    if (num.value.length == 0) {
        window.alert('digite um numero!')
    } else {
        let n = Number(num.value) 
        let c = 1 
        tab4.innerHTML = ''
        while (c <= 10) { 
            let item4 = document.createElement('option') 
            item4.text = `${n} / ${c} = ${(n/c).toFixed(2)}` 
            item4.value = `tab4${c}` 
            tab4.appendChild(item4) 
            c++ 
        }
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="estilo.css">
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <h1>Tabuada</h1>
</header>
<section>
    <div>
        <p>Numero: <input type="number" name="num" id="txtn">
        <input type="button" value="Gerar tabuada" onclick="tabuada()"></p>
    </div>
    
    <div>
        <select name="Tabuada4" id="seltab4" size="10" ></select>
    </div>

</section> 

<script src="aula06.js"></script>  
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Agora deu certo, eu tava quebrando cabeça com isso, sou novo na programação, obrigado !

Answer (score 3):

```
var x = 9.656;
x.toFixed(0);           // returns 10
x.toFixed(2);           // returns 9.66
x.toFixed(4);           // returns 9.6560
x.toFixed(6);           // returns 9.656000
```

Se entendi bem o que você quer fazer é isso não?

Comment: sim isso ai, mas não to sabendo como encaixar ele no meu codigo, sempre que eu tento colocar ele da algum erro, da uma olhada no meu codigo dei uma editada nele agora da pra entender melhor como ele ta

Comment: Tentar colocar assim: item4.text = \`${n} / ${c} = ${(n/c).toFixed(2)}`;